# Two identical TF2 items with different levels?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I discovered two items with different levels. They have identical names, symbols, and descriptions in my backpack:

[image]

[image]

Why are the levels different? Are the items identical? If there is a difference, what is it?

Comment: There was a time when item levels of weapons were random. These days, weapon item levels are fixed, but cosmetics have random levels.

Comment: @Powerlord I read about cosmetics that they have a level if there are fewer than 100 people who crafted the item before you did. If your item's number is bigger than 100, no number is displayed. But there apparently are 3rd party tools which can display the number anyways. I wouldn't call that random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TF2 Wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_levels):

> The majority of items in Team Fortress 2 have levels associated with them. Levels, viewed with the item name in the loadout menu, are purely cosmetic and do not modify the effectiveness of any weapon or item.

The item level is purely cosmetic.  It serves no other purpose.  So basically, yes these weapons are the same.